# How to add a typeorm in nuxt 3

Tags: orm, nuxt.js, typeorm, nuxtjs3

I create an typeorm ESM project by running the command

> npx typeorm init --name MyProject --database sqlite--module esm

as explained on https://typeorm.io. Running the project, everything works fine.
Then I create a nuxt 3 project: "npx nuxi init nuxt-project". Then I supplement the contents of the package.json and tsconfig.json files in the nuxt project with the appropriate typeorm values.

```
package.json:
    {
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "preview": "nuxt preview",
        "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
        "start": "node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts",
        "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
        "nuxt": "3.0.0",
        "ts-node": "10.9.1",
        "typescript": "4.9.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@npmcli/fs": "^3.1.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "sqlite3": "^5.1.4",
        "typeorm": "^0.3.11"
      }
    }
tsconfig.json:
    {
      // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
      "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
          "lib": [
             "es2021"
          ],
          "target": "es2021",
          "module": "es2022",
          "moduleResolution": "node",
          "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
          "outDir": "./build",
          "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
          "experimentalDecorators": true,
          "sourceMap": true
       }
    }
```

I copy the entity, the configured data-source, the base and add code to the App.vue.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import "reflect-metadata"
import { User } from "./db/entity/User.js"
import { AppDataSource } from "./db/data-source";

AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => {
    const user = new User()
    user.firstName = "Timber"
    user.lastName = "Saw"
    user.age = 25
    await AppDataSource.manager.save(user)
    const users = await AppDataSource.manager.find(User)
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users)
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtWelcome />
  </div>
</template>
```

I run a nuxt project and get an error:

> [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Column type for
> User#firstName is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you
> have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in
> tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on
> top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity
> imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must
> explicitly provide a column type.

Just in case, I add import reflect-metadata before the entity, but the error doesn't go away. I wonder if there is a good wizard who will guide me to the right path?

By the way, before that I tried to work with Sequelize, and also failed. It didn't fail on reflect-metadata, but:

```
Could not resolve "pg-hstore": const hstore = require("pg-hstore")
```

Any orm will work for me (that allows working with oracle, so Prisma is unfortunately out of the question). Any advice or an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the User entity: `@Column('text',{nullable:true})`.